# How did the pulling get into the term "Schraubenzieher"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

There are two synonymous terms for screwdriver, "Schraubenzieher" and "Schraubendreher". "Schraube" means screw. The "driver" part of is translated to "zieher" meaning "puller", or "dreher" meaning "turner".

The word "Schraubenzieher" makes no sense to me, because it can not pull screws. It is even a tool that can not pull anything at all. And screws are things that can not be pulled in a way that is related to being a screw. (A screw can be pulled like a nail, but that means not using it as a screw, and requires a different tool than a screwdriver.) More so, it seems to me that a "screw" is a development based on the simpler device "nail" to make it not possible to pull it. That a screw can not be pulled is not only a property of a screw, not only a prominent and fundamental property, it is the whole base of it's existence.

I see that "Schraubendreher" is the more technical term, and "Schraubenzieher" is somewhat informal. But independent of that, the word "Schraubenzieher" exists.

Comment: Maybe it has to with the verb "festziehen" because if you tighten a screw = dann "ziehst Du sie fest." But I don't know the ancient times. (and yes, as a child I wondered too)

Comment: When I was a child, only mechanical engineering nerds said *Schraubendreher*. That thing was simply a *Schraubenzieher* for us.

Comment: compare *spanner* in English - nothing "spans" there as well.

Comment: Counter question: Why is German *drehen* cognate with *throw*, not *draw*. And *enthrall*? What does G. *drall* have to do with *thrill* or *drill*, or *trawler* (Schlepper?).

Comment: @vectory "Drall" is "to spin", and a drill is a tool working based on spinning.  German "Drehen" is "to turn" - I do not see the relation to "throw" (Werfen)?

Comment: No no no, a *dralle Blondine* is not a spinner, but a proper, perky, solid, strapped blonde. The relation to *throw* is cognancy according to dictionary entries. So, "it, the screw-trewer, doesn't throw screws, lol" could be asked as well. Throw looks closer to drive than drehen, too.

Comment: @vectory  you are right about "a dralle Blondine". But there is also "der Drall" - I meant that one, but the other seems to originate from the spinning too.

Comment: I think the "driver" in screwdriver is "to drive" treiben/antreiben/hineintreiben

Comment: @Volker-Siegel that comparison is trife. It's obvious, not noteworthy, and occluding the allusion to *throw*, *werfen*. Compare *den Motor anwerfen*, *to throw on the engine*

Answer (score 6):

The [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schraubenzieher#Geschichte_und_Bezeichnung) states

> Der Begriff Schraubenzieher hatte das Einziehen bzw. Festziehen einer Holzschraube im Holz zum Ursprung.

So the origin seems to be indeed "Festziehen" (= pulling tight).

Comment: Interesting. I assume "festziehen" comes from the nautical world, then

Comment: @npst  How comes that? I do not see any relation of *festziehen* to nautics. (And I am a hobby sailor.)

Comment: Just a notion. I thought festziehen of a Schraube would have derived from the word Schraubenzieher. The other thing I imagine being festziehable are ropes, as encountered on sailor-type ships.

Comment: "Eine Schraube einziehen" habe ich noch nicht gehört, aber "anziehen". Beim Schraubenzieher kann man auch oft einen Schraubenschlüssel ansetzen und so die Drehbewegung durch eine tangentiale Zugkraft bewirken.

Comment: @user-unknown, man kann sich auch schicke Kleidung *anziehen*. Ich denke aber, weder das eine noch das andere wäre die Ursprüngliche Bedeutung. Immerhin wäre sonst der Schraubenschlüssel der wahre Schraubenzieher. Die Herkunft von *Anzug, feiner Zwirn* und eben *sich anziehen* wäre wohl für eine neue Frage gut.

Comment: @vectory: Ich weiß nicht, was Dein Kleidungsbeispiel ausdrücken soll. Bei den meisten Kleidungsstücken (Socken, Hemd, Hose) sind Ziehbewegungen (sich ewas überziehen) Teil des Bewegungsablaufs. Beim Hut und Schal vielleicht nicht. Der Schraubenzieher taugt zum Schrauben an- und festziehen, egal wie viele Schraubenschlüssel Du auf den Verhandlungstisch packst, die ja auch Mutternzieher heißen sollten, wenn es danach ginge. Außerdem kann man diese natürlich auch drücken und drehen - also nenn sie doch Mutterndrücker oder Mutterndreher. Oder Mutternlöser.

Answer (score -2):

Man sagt *eine Schraube fest ziehen, fest anziehen*, ganz einfach eigentlich. Die Details sind sicher komplizierter. Vgl. En. *tense, dense*, "gespannt, dicht", Niederdeutsch *densen* "ziehen".

Merke: *drehen* in der Fachsprache bedeutet *mit der CNC-Fräse herstellen*, doch die Bezeichnung ist sicherlich älter, siehe dazu den Beruf *Dreher*, bzw *Drechsler* (s. [drechseln](https://www.dwds.de/wb/drechseln). Vgl. auch *Drahtzieher*? Oder eher *Zwirn* und eben *Draht*, jeweils zu *zwirbeln* bzw. *drehen*.

Der Schraubendreher wäre daher etwas ganz anderes. Ich sage also weiterhin Schraubenzieher.

Comment: Nur so nebenbei: Ich bezweifle, dass man mit einer CNC-Fräse ein Drehteil herstellen kann bzw. dass der Mann, der vor einer *Fräse* steht, ein *Dreher* ist.

Comment: Dass das Wort Drehen in der Fachsprache auch für den Einsatz einer Fräse verwendet wird bedeutet nicht, dass es nicht auch für andere Tätigkeiten benutzt wird. Diese Regel lässt sich auch ein Dreher nicht so einfach andrehen, sondern er dreht sich vielleicht genervt ab.

Comment: Ich habe danach nicht recherchiert, halte es aber für plausibel, das Drehen sei eine der Grundtechniken der Materialbearbeitung, soweit *drechseln* ein ererbtes Wort ist.

Comment: @userunknown Dein Kommentar zeigt, dass du mit der Fachsprache wohl eher nicht so vertraut bist: Ein *Dreher* *dreht* an einer *Drehmaschine*, während ein *Fräser* an einer *Fräsmaschine* *fräst*. Die Mechaniker sind da sehr genau. (Allerdings spielt ein Geiger auch nicht Trompete)

Comment: Irgendwie ist das keine Antwort auf die Frage. Dafür aber ziemlich viel obiter dictum. Daher gebe ich hier -1

Comment: @tofro: Mag sein, ich behaupte auch nicht mich damit auszukennen. Der Inhalt, auf den es in meiner Aussage ankam, war, dass in der Fachsprache "Drehen" für 2 Dinge stehen kann, bei denen sich aus dem Kontext fast immer ergibt, was gemeint ist. Also das Arbeiten an einer Drehbank nicht an der Fräse. Gemerkt.

Comment: Vielleicht heißt der "Dreher" deswegen heute auch "Zerspanungsmechaniker".

Comment: Der Dreher macht beides. Als der Begriff *Dreher* etabliert wurde, waren Fräsmaschinen teuer und superexotisch. Nicht-Drehteile wurden damals auf dem Schnellholbler gemacht, auch *Stoßmaschine* genannt. Dadurch wurde aus dem Bediener aber noch lange kein *Stoßer*. Ein Dreher mit ein wenig Grips kann übrigens auch mit der Drehmaschine fräsen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach nagut, wenn darin keine klare Antwort zu erkennen ist, muss ich das wohl hinnehmen, und die top antwort abwählen, die auf's gleiche hinausläuft.

Comment: @vectory Für mich klingt das ein bisschen so, als würdest du den Downvote persönlich nehmen. Wie ich deine Antwort bewerte, hat doch nichts mit anderen Antworten zu tun. In jedem Fall sollten Downvotes nicht aus Trotz geschehen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach wenngleich ich die Meinung nicht in abrede stelle, ich wäre trotzig oder schlechten Gewissens, habe ich doch nur einen einfachen logischen Schluss gezogen, nachdem mir zweifel an meiner eigenen Antwort die Toleranzschwelle überschritten, soweit meiner Antwort eine Erklärung dieser Bedeutung und der weitere Bezug zur Alt-Sprache fehlt, sowie der Vergleich zu *densen* ad-hoc und eventuell irreführend ist.

Comment: Mir ist unklar, was tense/dense mit der Frage zu tun hat. Sagt man auch Schraubendenser?